# Things I can't do when I use php json_encode in response to an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please, is there someone who can shine me a light on this issue?

I'm sending an ajax request to a php file.
Everything was ok until I changed dataType from 'html to 'json'.

In the attempt to debug,
I started to put these 3 lines of code after certain points in the php file :

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(Array('message' => 'success'));
die();
```

This is what I found:

1. I can't use require_once to require classes but I can only use include: in the first case ajax gives me error, in the second it gives me the message 'success' as it should.
2. I can't use global variables within php file, only default variables.
3. I can't use the static methods of the classes previously included like MyClass::myStaticMethod(), only instances.
4. Maybe other things I've not yet discovered...

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?
Where can I find a list of php features that I can't use?
Is there a way to overcome the problem since I need those features?

Comment: exactly what error do you get in each of the three cases?

Comment: What you found is incorrect. You can do whatever you want before you output anything, as long as this does not break the format you want to achieve. Which will only happen if whatever you do before the final output produces own or breaks the final output (e.g. abort script execution due to fatal errors/uncaught exceptions).

Comment: I was completely off the road.

Comment: When Ajax gave me error it was: xhr.status: 200 and thrownError: something like 'unespected character <' . But the real error was a typing mistake in the class path of a require_once. All other errors were just a snowball effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server side you can do whatever you want as long as you respect the rules of JSON.
As a methodology, you can start building an static JSON file that works. Then piece by piece replacing its parts with the equivalent generated by PHP, that means (and is limited to), headers and content

On browser side, what you need is a predefined format (the output of your PHP script), there is no way to know if required_once or global variables were used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look

```
  <?php
        //1st Situation 

          header('Content-type: application/json');
          echo json_encode(Array('message' => 'success'));

   ?>
         //respective JS would be 
  <script>
              var json = ajax_response;

  </script>


  <?php
         //2nd Situation with no content header (html default)
          echo json_encode(Array('message' => 'success'));

   ?>
  //respective JS would be 


  <script>
              var json =$.parseJSON(ajax_response);

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do on the server side is to set the content-type to application/json, encode your data using the json_encode function and output it.

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

You can test it out for example in console by running this line:

```
$.ajax({url: 'data.php'})
// Response: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Let me know if u finding difficulty.

Thanks